# Is there a performance difference between using an aggregate function vs an already aggregated column in the ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, hive, hiveql

Ideally I would like to know this for hive, but other perspectives are also very welcome.

```
select a, sum(b) as c
from x
group by a
order by sum(b);
```

vs

```
select a, sum(b) as c
from x
group by a
order by c;
```

Comment: there should be no appreciable differences. The query optimizer should consider the two queries as identical

Comment: @scaisEdge can you reference this comment? This would be an answer

Comment: @Martin   .. a deep  look inside  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/statement-optimization.html

Comment: @Martin  .. i have posted  an asnwer  with the main link for the optimization of the part related to the question ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading deeper the statement optimization  for mysql   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/statement-optimization.html

there should be no appreciable differences. The query optimizer consider the two queries as identical

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html

remember that essentially the two query differ just for the use of the alias  and this i explicitally solved  by query optimizer

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the source.